# Panel co-integration Westerlund test and Pedroni co-integration test

Tags: panel-data, cointegration

My data is non-stationary. So in order to check for co-integration I used Westerlunds test but it showed not co-integrating relationships. But on doing a Pedronis co-integration test, it shows that there is cointegration. What is happening?
My data also shows cross sectional dependence.

Answer (score 0):

Pedroni's test only allows for very simple forms of cross-sectional dependence. So the rejection of that test might be spurious because not all underlying assumptions for the test to be valid are met. I would therefore feel it is more plausible to trust Westerlund's test here.

(That said, it is also perfectly possible for two tests to disagree even if both tests' assumptions are met.)